# Ios Xcode Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an app with collection view and a cell within this collection view that redirects to external link.

Whenever that link opens the app crashs in the background and gives on the debugger:

> "Terminated due to memory issue".

If I just press home button the app continues working just fine.

```
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)) Portrait = NO;
else if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)) Portrait = YES;
else Portrait = [self getStatusBarOrientations];

if(indexPath.row == 4 && indexPath.section == 0)
{
    NewsListCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell4"  forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([languageID isEqualToString:@"1025"])
    {
        cell.title.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"جريدة اليوم %@", [self.pdfCoverDict valueForKey:@"PdfDate"]];
        [cell.contentView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1)];
    } else {
        cell.title.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Today's Edition %@", [self.pdfCoverDict valueForKey:@"PdfDate"]];
    }
    NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[self.pdfCoverDict valueForKey:@"CoverImage"]];
    [cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:imageUrl];
    cell.imageViewWidth.constant = Portrait ? 246 : 331;
    cell.imageViewHeight.constant = Portrait ? 350 : 471;
    return cell;

} else if(indexPath.row == 0) {
    NewsListCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.title.text = [self.channelKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    cell.backView.hidden = [channelID isEqualToString:@"1"] ? (indexPath.section == 0 ? YES : NO) : YES;
    if([languageID isEqualToString:@"1025"]) {
        [cell.contentView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1)];
    } else {
        [cell.contentView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1)];
        [cell.title setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1)];
    }
    return cell;
} else {

    NSInteger row;
    if(indexPath.row != 1 && indexPath.row != 2 && indexPath.row != 3) {
        row = indexPath.row - 2;
    } else {
        row = indexPath.row - 1;
    }
    NSMutableArray * articles =  [self.channelArticles valueForKey:[self.channelKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
     //        if(row < articles.count) {
    NSString *articleImage = [[articles objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"ArticleMedia"];
    NSString *cellIdentifier;
    NSString *articleLangID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[articles objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"LanguageID"]];

    if(indexPath.section == 0) {
        switch (indexPath.row)
        {
            case 1:
                if(![articleImage isEqualToString:@""]) cellIdentifier = @"Cell1";
                else cellIdentifier = @"CellNoImg";
                break;
            case 2:
                if(![articleImage isEqualToString:@""]) cellIdentifier = @"Cell2";
                else cellIdentifier = @"CellNoImg";
                break;
            case 3:
                if(![articleImage isEqualToString:@""]) cellIdentifier = @"Cell3";
                else cellIdentifier = @"CellNoImg";
                break;
            case 5:
                if(![articleImage isEqualToString:@""]) cellIdentifier = @"Cell5";
                else cellIdentifier = @"CellNoImg";
                break;
            case 6:
                if(![articleImage isEqualToString:@""]) cellIdentifier = @"Cell5";
                else cellIdentifier = @"CellNoImg";
                break;
            default:
                if(![articleImage isEqualToString:@""]) {
                    if([channelID isEqualToString:@"1"]) cellIdentifier = @"Cell6";
                    else cellIdentifier = @"Cell5";
                } else {
                    cellIdentifier = @"CellNoImg";
                }
                break;
        }
    } else {
        if(![articleImage isEqualToString:@""]) cellIdentifier = @"Cell5";
        else cellIdentifier = @"CellNoImg";
    }


    NewsListCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if([[[articles objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"LabelName"] isEqualToString:@""]) {
        cell.labelNameHeight.constant = 0;
    } else {
        cell.labelNameHeight.constant = 21;
    }
    cell.labelName.text = [[articles objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"LabelName"];

    cell.title.text = [[articles objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"MainHeadline"];

    if(indexPath.row == 3 && indexPath.section == 0) {
        if(![articleImage isEqualToString:@""]) cell.titleHeight.constant = [self lineCountForLabel:cell.title labelWidth:cell.frame.size.width - Portrait ? 254 : 337] * 35;
        else cell.titleHeight.constant = [self lineCountForLabel:cell.title labelWidth:cell.frame.size.width - 10] * 35;
    } else {
        cell.titleHeight.constant = [self lineCountForLabel:cell.title labelWidth:cell.frame.size.width - 10] * 35;
    }

    NSString *authorTime = [self getAuthorTime:[articles objectAtIndex:row]];
    if([authorTime isEqualToString:@""]) {
        cell.authorTimeHeight.constant = 0;
    } else {
        cell.authorTimeHeight.constant = 21;
    }
    cell.authorTime.text = authorTime;

    NSString *details = [[articles objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"Introduction"];
    cell.details.attributedText = [self getAttributedString: details language: articleLangID];

    if([cellIdentifier isEqualToString:@"CellNoImg"]) {
        defaultLines = 5;
        if([cell.authorTime.text isEqualToString:@""]) defaultLines++;
        if([cell.labelName.text isEqualToString:@""]) defaultLines++;
        if(cell.titleHeight.constant / 35 == 1) defaultLines++;
        cell.details.numberOfLines = defaultLines;
    }

    if(indexPath.section == 0) {
        switch (indexPath.row)
        {
            case 2:
                cell.imageViewWidth.constant = Portrait ? 240 : 323;
                cell.imageViewHeight.constant = Portrait ? 151 : 199;
                break;
            case 3:
                cell.imageViewWidth.constant = Portrait ? 240 : 323;
                cell.imageViewHeight.constant = Portrait ? 151 : 199;
            case 5:
                cell.imageViewWidth.constant = Portrait ? 240 : 323;
                cell.imageViewHeight.constant = Portrait ? 151 : 199;
                break;
            case 6:
                cell.imageViewWidth.constant = Portrait ? 240 : 323;
                cell.imageViewHeight.constant = Portrait ? 151 : 199;
                break;
            default:
                cell.imageViewWidth.constant = Portrait ? 240 : 323;
                cell.imageViewHeight.constant = Portrait ? 151 : 199;
                break;
        }
    } else {
        cell.imageViewWidth.constant = Portrait ? 240 : 323;
        cell.imageViewHeight.constant = Portrait ? 151 : 199;
    }

    if (![articleImage isEqualToString:@""]) {
        NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:articleImage];
        [cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:imageUrl];

    } else {
        [cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:nil];
    }

    if([articleLangID isEqualToString:@"1025"]) {
        [cell.contentView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1)];
        cell.labelName.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        cell.title.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        cell.authorTime.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        cell.details.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    } else {
        if (indexPath.row == 3) {
            [cell.contentView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1)];
            [cell.labelName setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1)];
            [cell.title setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1)];
            [cell.authorTime setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1)];
            [cell.details setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1)];
            [cell.imageView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1)];
        }
        cell.labelName.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        cell.title.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        cell.authorTime.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        cell.details.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    }
    return cell;

}
```

}

Comment: How much memory is the app using?  If you run with Instruments, it will show you what is being allocated.

Comment: memory is being stable, about 20MB but stills gives memory issue and that is specifically happening when trying to scroll the collection view and directly click on the link.

Comment: arent you reusing the collection view cells ?

Comment: you need to provide more details about the issue. Show us code of how you are reusing the cells

Comment: yes I reuse the collection view cells

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What device is this happening on? Once your app is in the background you can expect for it to be killed at any time - it doesn't have to be using excessive memory.

If the new foreground app wants more memory, the OS will give it as much as it can. It will send a memory warning to any backgrounded apps. If they don't respond by reducing the memory footprint, or the foreground app still wants more memory, then the background apps are killed.

Your app isn't crashing, it is being killed by the OS because it is no longer the foreground app and its resources are needed elsewhere.

Comment: I am using Ipad mini device

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem - terminated due to memory issue when the memory usage still low.

Then I found the reason: actually the memory allocated very quickly.

Just because the memory was destroyed very quickly, so it seems memory usage is still very low.
You can use instruments to see current memory usage / total memory usage
[picture to explain how view memory usage / total memory usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGvOA.png)
The picture is found from internet, but explain the problem clearly.
You will find this value in the rapid reduction, the the area of ​​light color is quickly grow, then your app crash due to memory issue when memory usage still low.

Answer (score 0):

I would check elsewhere in your code. The answer is more than likely that you have a retain cycle somewhere and are leaking memory. Search for items like closures where you may have **neglected to declare self as weak (may be nil) or unowned (never nil in that instance but that self is not owned by the closure object)**

```
[weak self]
```

**or**

```
[unowned self]
```

Instruments can help you but a detailed inspection of the objects in use (controllers, custom view classes, custom tableviewcell subclasses, tableviewrowaction delegate methods that might reference self, etc.) will be required. When you find the suspect area and make corrections, you should test the behavior on your device and see if you can spot the leak in instruments.

Verify that your fix removes the leak, test more and verify that no other leaks are happening (most likely it's more than one).

Answer (score 0):

If this problem only occur when the app is not active, then it may also be caused by other (memory hungry) apps on the test device. To rule this out, disable Background App Refresh of other apps and/or close other apps and/or restart the device.